# Почему не работает атрибут ref?

Tags: reactjs

```js
import React from "react";



class Main extends React.Component {
 constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
   divStyle: {
    width:"1000px",
    height: "500px",
    outline: "1px solid red"
   },
   move: {
    width:"200px",
    height:"100px",
    outline: "1px solid green"

   }
  }

 }


  MouseDown(e){

                console.log(this.ourDiv);
  }

 

 render() {

  return( 
   <div>
    <div style={this.state.divStyle}>
     <div style={this.state.move} ref={(ourDiv)=> this.ourDiv = ourDiv} onClick ={this.MouseDown}></div>
    </div>
   </div>
   )

 }
}



export default Main;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
<div style={this.state.move} ref={(ourDiv) => { this.ourDiv = ourDiv; }} onClick={() => {this.MouseDown()}}></div>
```

или просто забиндить вашу функцию MouseDown:

```
<div style={this.state.move} ref={(ourDiv) => this.ourDiv = ourDiv} onClick={this.MouseDown.bind(this)}></div>
```

Почему у вас не получалось вызвать ref можете прочитать тут:
https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: Точно забыл bind сделать